# Symfony 4.4 - "No route found for "GET /""

Tags: symfony, symfony-4.4

I'm getting the following Error on the server:

```
Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: "No route found for "GET /"" at ../vendor/symfony/http-kernel/EventListener/RouterListener.php line 136
```

Routes are properly defined within /config/routes/annotations.yaml

```
controllers:
  resource: ../../src/Controller/
  type: annotation

kernel:
  resource: ../../src/Kernel.php
  type: annotation
```

On local, the application works without any issues. It happens only on the host where I deploy the Symfony application. Cache has been cleared with `php bin/console cache:clear`. I even deleted `var/*` and `vendor/*` and did a fresh install of the packages via Composer (got it to the latest version by the way).
Regarding application, it is - Symfony v4.4.19 Flex.

Comment: Does 'bin/console debug:router' show any routes defined?

Comment: Yes, it shows me all the routes. Also, didn't have any errors when I ran composer to install packages.

Comment: So it is probably a web server configuration issue.  If you are using apache then maybe you need an .htaccess file.  If you have not already, read through the docs on deployment.  Lots of possible blocking points.

Comment: try executing composer require "symfony/apache-pack". Or did you already install it?